# Network Policy to access Google Cloud Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have a GKE cluster running that hosts an app that needs access to the storage buckets. For that purpose I am making use of `gsutils`.

The current Network Policy is very restrictive and I only allow access to endpoints that really need it. With my policy in place, if I login to my Pod and run `gsutil ls`, I get

```
jenkins@ptbkn:~$ gsutil ls
INFO 0826 18:13:03.702595 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #1...
INFO 0826 18:14:05.556362 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #2...
INFO 0826 18:15:09.331261 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #3...
```

But the moment I take down the Network Policy, I can see all my buckets.

```
jenkins@ptbkn:~$ gsutil ls
gs://abc/
gs://xyz/
.
.
```

Now Im unsure of how can I specify the Network Policy rules. Meaning that Im unaware of what IP ranges / hostnames / Ports should I add to my network policy to whitelist Google Cloud Storage. Can someone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding dl.google.com and www.googleapis.com this will help for gsutil, also in this [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#example_2) the example mentions an IP range `199.36.153.4/30` for Google APIs and Services.